# what does servlet response do

Tags: java, servlets, response

Now sorry for asking such a silly question,
Now if there is a form filed

```
<form action="formServlet">
number<input type="text" name="num">
<input type="submit" value =add>
</form>
```

and then a request is send to servlet,where it handles it and sends a response,now my question is when it sends the response where does this out.println() of response takes it to,a page from where the request was made..or it generates a new page??

and when we send a ajax request request using get or post method,the response is send to the jquery itself?so where does this response goes?

Comment: What `out.println()`?

Comment: like if we take printwriter out=response.getWritter();

Comment: You may want to add the relevant part of your `servlet` to your question.

Comment: See if this [Servlet step-by-step](http://www.oxxus.net/tutorials/servlet/servlet-stepbystep) tutorial helps any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a browser sends a non-AJAX request, it takes the content of the response, and replaces the current page with the content of the response (unless the user or the HTML code chose to open the link in a new tab or frame, in which case the current page is left as is, and a new tab or frame is opened, and contains the content of the response).

When it sends an AJAX request, the JavaScript code receives the response and does whatever it wants with it.